# Why is the scrolling waveform not appearing?

Tags: c++, audio, juce

I am trying to create a scrolling waveform using Juce's AudioVisualiserComponent, however I can't seem to do so.

I have an AudioSampleBuffer variable called waveform and I have assigned it to the buffer of the incoming audio data

```
waveform = *bufferToFill.buffer;
```

I need to pass waveform to another class that controls the GUI that displays the waveform

```
AudioSampleBuffer FilePlayer::getBuffer()
{
return waveform;
}
```

In the GUI class I try to implement the waveform like so

```
addAndMakeVisible(&waveform);
waveform.pushBuffer(filePlayer.getBuffer());
waveform.setColours(Colours::black, Colours::red);
waveform.setSamplesPerBlock(256);
waveform.setBufferSize(1024);
```

The program works although the waveform is never visible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the bounds of your `AudioVisualiserComponent` using `Component::setBounds()`?

Comment: Yes I have, its in the resize function